# How to format a cell formula in lazarus FPSpreadsheet?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

I have a problem in Lazarus using FPSpreadsheet, where I am not able to define a format for a cell.
ex: inline formatting,

```
 Value := 1500.60
 MySheet.WriteNumber(0,1,Value, nfFixedTh,2);
```

I have this result in A2, 1,500.60, but when I define a formula I can't get this formatting.

ex: A2 = 1500.60
A3 = 260.00

```
MySheet.WriteFormula(0,4,'=SUM(A2:A3)');
```

The Result is 1760.6, how to format the result cell, so that it looks like this 1,760.60
In excel this is done like this:

```
MySheet.Range[A2,A3].NumberFormat := '###,##0.00';
```

But I am not able to do the same with FPSpreadsheet
tks

I tried like this:

```
 A2 = 1500.6
 A3 = 260.00
 MySheet.WriteFormula(0,4,'=SUM(A2:A3)');
 MyCell := MySheet.GetCell(0,4);
 MyCel^.NumberFormat := nfFixedTh;
```

The Result is 1760.6, how to format the result cell, so that it looks like this 1,760.60.
I also reversed calling

```
 MyCell := MySheet.GetCell(0,4); 
 MyCel^.NumberFormat := nfFixedTh;
```

before writing the formula

Comment: If the result cell is A4, then you set the format of that cell, just like you set A2 and A3, no?

Comment: The formatting that is in A2 and A3 in the example, works when it is excel, I cannot format the column where the result of the formula will be, A4

Comment: The first call should be to read the docs, eg: https://wiki.freepascal.org/FPSpreadsheet#Cell_formatting Formats can be defined for single cells as well as for rows or columns.

Comment: Hello Tom!
This is the problem I haven't found a way to format the cell before it receives the result.

Comment: Hello Tom!
This is the problem I haven't found a way to format the cell before it receives the result. I found this in the manual at Column and row formats about  the FormatIndex element of the row and column records format applied to the entire row or column. type TsWorksheet = class
   // Assign a format to a column or row
   procedure WriteColFormatIndex(ACol: Cardinal; AFormatIndex: Integer);
   procedure WriteRowFormatIndex(ARow: Cardinal; AFormatIndex: Integer);
 But I didn't find any reference about AFormatIndex

Answer (score 0):

The TsWorksheet has a bunch of formatting methods. Read the wiki article which Tom mentioned.

In your case, in order to format a number cell, you should call one of the WriteNumberFormat methods, like in the following example. BTW, it does not matter whether you apply the format before or after the cell received its value.

```pascal
program Project1;
uses
  fpsTypes, fpspreadsheet, xlsxOOXML;
var
  workbook: TsWorkbook;
  sheet: TsWorksheet;
begin
  workbook := TsWorkbook.Create;
  try
    sheet := workbook.AddWorksheet('Test');
    sheet.WriteNumber(1, 0, 1500.6);
    sheet.WriteNumber(2, 0, 260.0);
    sheet.WriteNumberFormat(4, 0, nfFixedTh, 2);
    sheet.WriteFormula(4, 0, 'Sum(A2:A3)');
    workbook.WriteToFile('test.xlsx', true);
  finally
    workbook.Free;
  end;
end.
```